# Disable buffer swapping in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering

Is there a way to disable buffer swapping in LibGDX every time the "render" call of **ApplicationListener** returns? I mean - I'm looking on some way to be able to tell the framework if I want the buffers swapped each frame.

The **Application** interface doesn't expose any such method, neither it is possible using static **Gdx.graphics** reference.

Side note: please refrain from answers saying I shouldn't or something in this flavor - I know what I need and why I need it.

Comment: Buffer swapping depends on the platform and the call to it is different with every implementation.. You could change the source for your target platform implentation to get what you want, otherwise I don't think it is possible. You can disable continouus rendering I think but I haven't done that yet. Just out of curiosity, why do you want to disable buffer swapping?

Comment: @cozmic Because I want to implement dirty rectangles optimization for rendering and swapping goes in my way.